# Uploading shapefle to Google Earth Engine

Tags: arcgis, shapefile, vertices, google-earth-engine

I need help uploading the following shapefile into Google Earth Engine:
http://myflorida-floridadisaster.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/a78a27e02f9d4a71a3c3357aefc35baf_4

When I go to my asset and upload it as a table I get an error saying that the vertices in the shapefile exceed that max 1 million cap within GEE. Is there anything else I can do to upload the file or reduce the number of vertices within the shapefile in arcGIS?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Simplify Polygon function in the ArcMap. You could find it from ArcToolbox> Cartography Tools> Generalization> Simplify Polygon.

Another way is: draw a big rectangle that completely covers your study area. This could be done in GEE itself.